# Help understanding a proof on why the Mandelbrot set is fractal

Tags: fractals, complex-dynamics

I was reading an excellent answer that was given on Quora [(found here)](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-Mandelbrot-set-a-fractal) that trys to explain why the Mandelbrot contains smaller approximate copies of itself.
Here's the section that I'm interested in:

> Let $f_c(z) = z^2 + c$, and consider the Taylor series of $f_c^n$
>   ($f_c$ iterated $n$ times) for some positive integer $n$:
>
> $$f_c^n(z) = f_c^n(0) + \tfrac12(f_c^n)''(0)z^2 + O(z^4)$$ (There
>   are no $z^1$ or $z^3$ terms because $f_c$ is an even function.) If we
>   scale everything by a factor of $k = \tfrac12(f_c^n)''(0)$, we end up
>   with    $$k f_c^n\bigl(\tfrac z k\bigr) = \tfrac12(f_c^n)''(0)f_c^n(0) + z^2 + O(z^4)$$
>       $$= f_{g_n(c)}(z) + O(z^4)$$ where $g_n(c) = \tfrac12(f_c^n)''(0)f_c^n(0)$.
>
> That is, for small $z$, **taking** $mn$ **iterations of** $f_c$
>   **works very similarly to taking** $m$ **iterations of** $f_{g_n(c)}$. So we can expect that $g_n(c)$ is in the Mandelbrot set iff $c$ is in
>   something that looks very similar to the Mandelbrot set.

So my question is why is the last paragraph true? Why is there a relation between taking $mn$ iterations of $f_c(z)$ and $m$ iterations of $f_{g_n(c)}(z)$, and why does this show that the Mandelbrot set contains smaller approximate copies of itself?

Comment: I find it notable that $3$ iterations of $f$ are similar to $1$ iteration of $f$ in three locations $c$, but only one of these is at the nucleus of a cardioid-like shape of a "baby Mandelbrot set island" (the other two are the nuclei of disc-like shapes).  Perhaps https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0701234v1 "On the shapes of elementary domains or why Mandelbrot Set is made from almost ideal circles?" V.Dolotin, A.Morozov will provide some clues?